# C# - Create Enumeraor that Get Values Randomly

Tags: c#, ienumerable, ienumerator

I want to create a `IEnumerable` class in C# that when get next value get it randomly from list of object

I want to get random value each time I want to get next for example I my list length is 100 and I get 1000 times value each time get random value

I create a below class but my program is hanged when create new instance from class

```
public class MyEnumerable:System.Collections.IEnumerable
{
    public int RegionID { get; set; }

    List<Medium> RankedList;
    MediaEnumerator pe;

    public MyList(int regionID)
    {
        RegionID = regionID;
        RankedList = ShowVideo.GetRankList(regionID);
        pe = new MediaEnumerator(RankedList);
    }

    public System.Collections.IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return (IEnumerator)(pe);
    }
}

public class MediaEnumerator : IEnumerator
{
    List<Medium> RankedList;
    int position = -1;

    public MediaEnumerator(List<Medium> list)
    {
        RankedList = list;
    }

    Random rnd = new Random();

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        position = rnd.Next(RankedList.Count);
        return true;
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        position = -1;
    }

    object IEnumerator.Current
    {
        get
        {
            return Current;
        }
    }

    public FileInfo Current
    {
        get
        {
            try
            {
                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(RankedList[position].MediaUrl);
                return fi;
            }
            catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume you have problem to finish iterating infinite enumerable? (As there no sample that shows what code actually hangs...)

Comment: You should post your real code. This one can't compile as the names of class and constructor differ (MyEnumerable, MyList).

Comment: @Euphoric I complete question, and my code is real code

Comment: @Fratyx this code is my real code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [iterators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dscyy5s0.aspx) with `Random` and infinite loop would be simplest solution.

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetRandomElements<T>(T[] elements)
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    while(true)
    {
        int index = rand.Next(0, elements.Length);
        yield return elements[index];
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is very big like, if you like please up vote my question. thank you a lot

Answer (score 2):

You can get *any* enumerable in a random order by mixing LINQ and GUID.

```
var randomOrder = originalEnumerable.OrderBy(o => new Guid());
```

Comment: I want to get random value each time I want to get next  
for example I my list length is 100 and I get 1000 times value  
each time get random value

Comment: Call this every time you want a random value.  var randomValue = originalEnumerable.OrderBy(o => new GUID()).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: @SteveLillis Yeah, and kill performance in the process. And possibly incorrect distribution.

Comment: @Euphoric as with all things, worry about performance when its an issue. If you're worried about distribution, you can do just as well with an alternative random value in the order by that will meet your distribution needs.  Your pattern is good, but it breaks the contract for enumerables that as a consumer I expect to be able to enumerate over the whole collection if I use foreach, yours will hang forever.

Comment: @SteveLillis You obviously never used LINQ's Take. If you are doing for-each without specifying the length you want means you are doing it wrong. Being able to easily handle infinite sequences are core principle of LINQ-like libraries.

Comment: @Euphoric please don't condescend. Take(x) specifies a clear pattern. Skip(x) also, in that they indicate a subset.  FirstOrDefault() also couldn't be clearer, nor could Single().  GetRandomElements(x) would also specify a clear pattern of Get X Random Elements. GetRandomElements() does not indicate anywhere that you will be getting an infinite set.  "can handle" infinite sequences is not the same as "convert my 10 item enumerable *into* an" infinite sequence.  Its additionally worth noting that all LINQ methods return a reproducible result set.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you always return true in MoveNext(), change this codes can may cause to your code work fine

but now there is a error that is the number of get random value is exactly number of your list length. but I fixed your code.

```
    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        position++;
        return (position < RankedList.Count);
        //position = rnd.Next(RankedList.Count);
        //return true;
    }
```

and change this code in MediaEnumerator

```
    public FileInfo Current
    {
        get
        {
            try
            {
                //FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(RankedList[position].MediaUrl);
                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(RankedList[rnd.Next(RankedList.Count)].MediaUrl);
                return fi;
            }
            catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This would limit count of all returned items to same amount as input list. This is not what OP wants.

Comment: @Euphoric I test this Code and Check That your comment is Correct